# Reference to know the history of Superintuitionistic (intermediate) logics

Tags: logic, math-history, intuitionistic-logic

There is any source in books or in the web about the history of development of the study of Superintuitionistic logics? By this concept I refer the wikipedia article called "Intermediate logic".

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't have my copy on hand right now but I suspect that the bibliography of [Chagrov/Zakharyaschev, *Modal logic*](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modal-logic-9780198537793?cc=us&lang=en&), if not the book itself, will be relevant. (This despite the title: CZ actually deals with both modal and superintuitionistic logics, and the relationships between them.)